# VMWare player - compiling server modules - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, vmware, vmware-player

While running Ubuntu 13.04 whenever the Linux kernel had been updated, this used to make vmware player happy:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Yesterday I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10 and lo and behold, the above workaround does not work anymore:

```
Unable to install all modules.  See log for details.
```

I assume by "See log" it means the files in /tmp/vmware-root/*log

```
root@hugin:/tmp/vmware-root# ls -ltr /tmp/vmware-root/
totalt 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3815 nov  6 13:54 vmware-apploader-17267.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-17693.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-17742.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-18701.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-18750.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-19100.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 nov  6 13:54 vmware-vmis-19149.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9250 nov  6 13:54 vmware-modconfig-17267.log

root@hugin:/tmp/vmware-root# tail /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-modconfig-17267.log
2013-11-06T13:54:28.950+01:00| modconfig| I120: Copied Module.symvers from "/tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vmci-only/Module.symvers" to "/tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vsock-only/Module.symvers".
2013-11-06T13:54:28.950+01:00| modconfig| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j8 -C /tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vsock-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2013-11-06T13:54:31.048+01:00| modconfig| I120: Successfully built vsock.  Module is currently at "/tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vsock.o".
2013-11-06T13:54:31.048+01:00| modconfig| I120: Found the vsock symvers file at "/tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vsock-only/Module.symvers".
2013-11-06T13:54:31.048+01:00| modconfig| I120: Installing vsock from /tmp/modconfig-wpDrtf/vsock.o to /lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/misc/vsock.ko.
2013-11-06T13:54:31.048+01:00| modconfig| I120: Registering file "/lib/modules/3.11.0-12-generic/misc/vsock.ko".
2013-11-06T13:54:31.400+01:00| modconfig| I120: "/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0/vmware-installer" exited with status 0.
2013-11-06T13:54:31.400+01:00| modconfig| I120: Registering file "/usr/lib/vmware/symvers/vsock-3.11.0-12-generic".
2013-11-06T13:54:31.764+01:00| modconfig| I120: "/usr/lib/vmware-installer/2.1.0vmware-installer" exited with status 0.
2013-11-06T13:54:31.786+01:00| modconfig| I120: We are now shutdown.  Ready to die!


root@hugin:/tmp/vmware-root# tail /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-apploader-17267.log 
2013-11-06T13:54:20.911+01:00| appLoader| I120: libglib-2.0.so.0 <SYSTEM>
2013-11-06T13:54:20.911+01:00| appLoader| I120: libz.so.1 <SYSTEM>
2013-11-06T13:54:20.911+01:00| appLoader| I120: libvmware-modconfig-console.so <SHIPPED>
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Shipped glib version is 2.24
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: System glib version is 2.38
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Using system version of glib.
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libgcc_s.so.1.
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libglib-2.0.so.0.
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Loading system version of libz.so.1.
2013-11-06T13:54:20.912+01:00| appLoader| I120: Loading shipped version of libxml2.so.2.
```

Answer (score 2):

See this answer at the vmware forums:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2282385

I'm quoting Rainmaker52's answer here (Rainmaker52, I hope you are ok with this):

> Patches for workstation 9.0.2 seem to apply cleanly to 2013 too.
> Only the "Virtual machine communication interface" seems to fail in starting, but VMWare workstation opens OK and VMs run fine.
>
> Starting VMware services:
>
> Virtual machine monitor                                             **done**
> Virtual machine communication interface                             **failed**
> VM communication interface socket family                            **done**
> Blocking file system                                                **done**
> Virtual ethernet                                                    **done**
> VMware Authentication Daemon                                        **done**
>
> # uname -a
> Linux laptop 3.11.0-rc6-minbcache-00008-gbe5d42a #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Aug 25 14:47:02 CEST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Patches to apply:
> When running kernel 3.10:
>
> For vmnet.tar: [See forum thread linked above. I don't have enough reputation to put more links in here]
>
> For vmblock.tar:  [See forum thread linked above. I don't have enough reputation to put more links in here]
>
> When running 3.11, apply this extra patch:  [See forum thread linked above. I don't have enough reputation to put more links in here]
>
> To apply:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
tar -xf vmblock.tar
cd vmnet-only
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/procfs.patch
cd ../vmblock-only
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/vmblock.3.10.patch
patch -p1 < ~/Downloads/vmblock.3.11.patch
cd ..
tar -cf vmblock.tar vmblock-only
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

> Good luck.

I have just tested this on my machine and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I followed the instructions to patch the vmware installation. Unfortunately to no avail. The problem is the same after the patches as it was before.